# PLSQL procedure, which gets the dependend package reference as a parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, refactoring

I hava an oracle PLSQL procedure which looks quite the same in three different packages.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACK_A 
AS
   PROCEDURE PROC_A
   IS 
      TYPE ref_c_data IS REF CURSOR RETURN data_rec%ROWTYPE;
      TYPE ref_c_items IS REF CURSOR RETURN items_rec%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
      ...
      PACK_A.PROC_B(ref_c_data, ref_c_items)
      ...
   END;
   PROCEDURE PROC_B
   -- This procedure is different in all three packages
   END;
END;
/
```

Now I want to extract `PACK_A.PROC_A` into a common package so that I don't have to maintain the same source three times. I think of sth. like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACK_A 
AS
   PROCEDURE PROC_A
   IS
      TYPE ref_c_data IS REF CURSOR RETURN data_rec%ROWTYPE;
      TYPE ref_c_items IS REF CURSOR RETURN items_rec%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
      PACK_COMMON.PROC_A(ref_c_data, ref_c_items)
   END;
   PROCEDURE PROC_B
   -- This procedure is different in all three packages
   END;
END;
/
```

The problem I have is that I have no idea of how to tell `PACK_COMMON.PROC_A` from which package `PACK_A`, `PACK_B` or `PACK_C` the procedure `PROC_B` should be called?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really had to do this, you'd need to supply a parameter to the common proc A and use that to say which proc B you wanted to call.

eg:

```
create package body pack_common
as
  procedure proc_a (p_proc_to_call varchar2)
  is
    ...
  begin
    ...
    if p_proc = 'PACK_A' then
       pack_a.proc_b;
    elsif p_proc = 'PACK_B' then
       pack_b.proc_b;
    ...
    end if;
    ...
  end proc_a;
end pack_common;
/
```

Comment: Thx, yes this is a workable solution. But I would prefer to supply the package as a reference. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by "as a reference"?

Comment: I mean an object reference of the package. I think for "ref coursors" there is a similar semantic behind.

Comment: to my knowledge, that's not possible. Another alternative is to split your proc_a into 2 common parts, and then call common.proc_a_pt_1, proc_b, common.proc_a_pt_2 in packages a, b and c